# How to tell python to not round the numbers?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm using python and I have a matrix where 1º column has the names and 2º column has the confidence. The matrix is called top_list.
Now I want to transform each column in one list which I did as:

```
classes = matrix(top_list).transpose()[0].getA()[0]  # Top class name

probs = matrix(top_list).transpose()[1].getA()[0]    # Confidence
```

The problem is that the confidences appear [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8xd.png) where the numbers are rounded.

How can I keep all the decimal places?

**UPDATE:**

My code is here:

```
classes = matrix(top_list).transpose()[0].getA()[0]  # Top class name
    classes = np.delete(classes, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])        # Delete first 5 elements
    probs = matrix(top_list).transpose()[1].getA()[0]    # Top class probability
    probs = np.delete(probs, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])            # Delete first 5 elements
    #print classes
    #print probs

    f = open('top_5_class_labels.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\n\n\n')
    f.write('Top 5 Class Labels [Final Solution] \n\n')
    f.write("{: <50} {: <15} \n\n".format('Predicted Classes', 'Probability'))

    for x in range(0, 5):
        idx = max(range(len(probs)), key=lambda i: probs[i])
        #print classes[idx]
        #print probs[idx]
        f.write("{: <50} {: <15} \n".format(classes[idx], probs[idx]))
        probs[idx] = 0
    f.close()
```

Comment: How can you tell that the numbers are rounded? What precision do you need?

Comment: @sobek In my matrix top_list, my confidence values look like 0.0178780518472. When I transpose them to a list called probs, my confidence value passes to 0.385755. I would like to keep my precision, higher as possible.

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the way you're displaying the numbers, not the way you're calculating them. Since you don't show that code we can't help you.

Comment: @MarkRansom I updated my question with my code.